# Formik onSubmit not triggering save function on submission?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, formik, formik-material-ui

```
    const AddTimeOffDialog = ({ openModal, closeModal }: AddTimeOffDialogType): JSX.Element => {

    const newValues: AddTimeOffFormType = {
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
    allDay: false,
    startTime: null,
    endTime: null,
    reason: '',
  };
    const initialValues: AddTimeOffFormType = newValues;
    const validationSchema = AddTimeOffValidationSchema(intl);

  const handleSaveTimeOff = (formValues: AddTimeOffFormType) => {
    console.log(formValues);
    console.log('submitted')
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      enableReinitialize
      validateOnBlur={false}
      validateOnChange={true}
      onSubmit={handleSaveTimeOff}
    >
      {(formProps) => {
        return (
          <Form id="timeOffForm" autoComplete="off">
            <Dialog open={openModal} onClose={() => closeModal}>
              <DialogTitle className={classes.dialogTitle}>
                <Typography className={classes.dialogTitleText}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="advisorScheduling.addTimeOff" />
                </Typography>
              </DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                <Grid container rowSpacing={2}>
                  <Grid item container xs={12} columnSpacing={3} justifyContent="center">
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <DatePickerWrapper
                        name="startDate"
                        label={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.startDate' })}`}
                        error={Boolean(formProps.touched.startDate && formProps.errors.startDate)}
                        helperText={
                          formProps.touched.startDate && formProps.errors.startDate ? formProps.errors.startDate : null
                        }
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <DatePickerWrapper
                        name="endDate"
                        label={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.endDate' })}`}
                        error={Boolean(formProps.touched.endDate && formProps.errors.endDate)}
                        helperText={
                          formProps.touched.endDate && formProps.errors.endDate ? formProps.errors.endDate : null
                        }
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={4} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                      <FormLabel>{intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.allDay' })}</FormLabel>
                      <RadioGroupWrapper
                        name="allDay"
                        options={[
                          { value: true, label: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.yes' }) },
                          { value: false, label: intl.formatMessage({ id: 'common.no' }) },
                        ]}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item container></Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item container xs={12} columnSpacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <TimePickerWrapper
                        name="startTime"
                        label={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.startTime' })}`}
                        error={Boolean(formProps.touched.startTime && formProps.errors.startTime)}
                        helperText={
                          formProps.touched.startTime && formProps.errors.startTime ? formProps.errors.startTime : null
                        }
                        disabled={formProps.values.allDay}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <TimePickerWrapper
                        name="endTime"
                        label={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.endTime' })}`}
                        error={Boolean(formProps.touched.endTime && formProps.errors.endTime)}
                        helperText={
                          formProps.touched.endTime && formProps.errors.endTime ? formProps.errors.endTime : null
                        }
                        disabled={formProps.values.allDay}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item container xs={12} columnSpacing={3}>
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                      <TextFieldWrapper
                        name="reason"
                        label={`${intl.formatMessage({ id: 'advisorScheduling.note' })}`}
                        onBlur={() => formProps.setFieldTouched('reason', true, true)}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button variant="outlined" form="timeOffForm" type="submit">
                  <FormattedMessage id="common.save" />
                </Button>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    closeModal();
                    formProps.resetForm();
                  }}
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  <FormattedMessage id="common.cancel" />
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

I am using Formik and MUI to build this form dialog. For some reason the onSubmit prop in Formik is not triggering my handleSaveTimeOff() function. I have a submit button inside DialogActions that points to the form id in Form. Not even a simple console.log() inside my function will get triggered. Any idea why that handleSaveTimeOff() isn't triggering on button click/form submission?

Comment: MUIs `Dialog` uses portals, so the the submit button is actually rendered outside the form making it not trigger properly. Try adding the `disablePortal` prop to the `Dialog`.

Comment: That didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in my form validation schema that was causing the function not to work. If you have this issue make sure your validation schema is set up correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).